# While Loop, show only 50 records and more?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a query on a page, which then echoes out a while loop to display ALL records. I want to limit this to 25 but also have a dynamic next/previous button so I can skip through the records. I've seen something similar but I cannot figure it out or find the tutorial I saw. I'm new to PHP so any help would be great.

```
<?PHP
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, firstname, surname FROM members WHERE createdby = '" . $_SESSION['myusername'] ."'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$id=$row[0];
echo ("<a href=profile.php?id=$id>".$row[1]." ".$row[2]."</a>");
}
?>
```

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE .. LIMIT $offset, 25`. Check out [MySQL Limit](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

Comment: It's called pagination. If you Google "php pagination tutorial" you'll find several resources that should be helpful.

Comment: Wont that just limit the records to 25? I want to be able to select the next 25 and previous as well.

Comment: Please be aware that 1) You are using the [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) mysql_ functions. 2) Your code is open to SQL injection attacks, as you don't use escaping.

Comment: At dynamic next/previous buttons you can use Ajax request that does the query with LIMIT again. In order to avoid making the same query twice you check in HTML if the data exists (ex <div> with class"page1") if yes show it, if not create it based on the result camed from the Ajax request. Pagination in php ..search on google tons of examples,classes, and use PDO or a PHP MVC Framework.

Answer (score 2):

The right solution is to limit the query. You can do that like this (notice the "LIMIT 50" in the end):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, firstname, surname FROM members WHERE createdby = '" . $_SESSION['myusername'] ."' LIMIT 50");
```

You can also break the while loop in PHP by counting:

```
$count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  $id=$row[0];
  echo ("<a href=profile.php?id=$id>".$row[1]." ".$row[2]."</a>");
  $count++;
  if ($count >= 50){
    break;
  }
}
```

Again, the right solution is to limit the query. The reason is that then PHP wont load more than 50 results into memory thereby saving resources, if the query matches, lets say, a million rows in the database.

The second solution will load all results into memory, and when it then loops over them, it will stop the loop after 50 (but all matched results will still have been loaded, but only 50 would have been used, and afterwards all results will be unset again).

Comment: I've just put this into my .php file and it works great, how would I go about making previous/next buttons to skip through the records?

Comment: Then you should use "LIMIT" with "OFFSET" like this: "LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50" for page 2 and so on. The page could then be set through the URL in a GET-variable called "page". The offset could then be counted like this: $offset = $_GET["page"] * 50

Answer (score 0):

You should do this by modification of the sql query.

```
$offset = (int)$_GET['offset'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, firstname, surname FROM members WHERE createdby = '" . $_SESSION['myusername'] ."' limit $offset, 25");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have only ugly solutions...however: the first is to store the results into a session var (array form),put a condition( if(!isset(session)) execute query),transform the next and prev buttons into two form with near a hidden input with the current page view value(or it can be the total visualized post,ex 25 50 75...).
When you click the prev/next button,the page will be reloaded and it will print the session[varname][currentindex] and so on...
Otherwise you can do a jquery Ajax call that will return an array with all the records and manage it JavaScript/jquery in this way you don't need to refresh the page.
**Edit**
The SQL limit is nicer but however you need a session where you store the fraction of visualized items( 25 50 75) and the two button form,in this way you will check next/prev and add or subtract 25 to the session and after set the new MySQL limit (from session to session+25)